# How to complete enable / disable a TkInter listbox in Python

Tags: python, listbox, tkinter

How can I simply disable a TkInter Listbox? It seems such a straightforward thing to do and possibly it is. In the simple example below, I've got a button which should toggle the state of the listbox from fully selectable to greyed and unselectable.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *

class MyDialog:
    def __init__(self, rootWin):
        self.rootWin_ = rootWin
        self.frame_ = Frame( self.rootWin_, borderwidth=10 )
        self.frame_.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.listBox_ = Listbox( self.frame_, height=4, width=30, selectbackground='#000000' )
        self.listBox_.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.lbEnabled_ = 1
        for item in [ 'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Indigo', 'Violet' ]:
            self.listBox_.insert(END, item)
        self.button_ = Button( self.frame_, text='Disable', command=self.onEnableDisable)
        self.button_.grid(row=1, column=0)

    def go(self):
        self.rootWin_.mainloop()

    def onEnableDisable(self):
        if self.lbEnabled_ == 1:
            self.button_.config( text='Enable' )
            # TODO enable the list box
            self.lbEnabled_ = 0
        else:
            self.button_.config( text='Disable' )
            # TODO disable the list box
            self.lbEnabled_ = 1

def main():
    myDlg = MyDialog(Tk())
    myDlg.go()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've tried a few things including changing state:

```
self.listBox_.config( state = DISABLED )
```

The reference documentation I've found suggests you can set this with the state attribute:

> **state**  By default, a listbox is in the NORMAL state. To make the listbox unresponsive to mouse events, set this option to DISABLED.

However, if I try this, all I get is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1345, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./example.py", line 24, in onEnableDisable
    self.listBox_.config( state = DISABLED )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1139, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1130, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: unknown option "-state"
```

As you can see, I'm using a pretty old version (2.4) of python which probbaly won't help, but I have no control over. Any ideas?

Comment: You appear to be using python 2.4, is that correct? Have you tried upgrading to a more modern version of python? What you are doing is correct, so this is likely a bug in that old version which was probably corrected  years ago.

Comment: Yes, that's right. No control over it I'm afraid - though see my comment on mgilson's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed code works for me (python 2.6, OS-X).  It actually looks like `Tkinter` is doing the right thing from the traceback.  Perhaps you're also using an old version of `Tcl/Tk` which could also cause the problem you're seeing.  If you don't have control over the python version, do you have control over the Tk version?

Comment: Thanks. It's a client machine so I'm limited and can't really put forward a good case for upgrading as they have other dependencies and this is really a nice to have rather than mission critical, but ... I had a scan around and found a 2.6 version of Python hidden away, together with corresponding TkInter, so I switched to that and it works a treat. Even other little features that I'd given up on (such as justification) now look nice. Thanks very much for pushing me in the right direction!